# Miktex with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: miktex, ubuntu, pspicture

I have a problem with Miktex when I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. The Miktex is not showing figures between

```
\begin{pspicture}   \end{pspicture}
```

I have `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.11 (MiKTeX 22.8.28)`. I am running with `XeLatex`. I have the following warnings in the log file

```
Font shape `TU/txr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead
Font shape `TU/txr/b/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/txr/m/n' instead
Font shape `TU/txr/m/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/txr/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

The commands like `\psline` `\psdots` are not recognized